# Jquery $.post doesn't work

Tags: jquery-post

Is there a trick to making this function work?

I want the page to be submitted to test.aspx upon button clicking and POST param in the following way:

my html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return submittotest();"><span>Click me</span></a>
```

js

```
function submittotest() {

     $.post("test.aspx", { param: "paramvalue" });

}
```

Comment: $.post makes an ajax request, is this what you want, or are you trying to submit a form ?

Comment: submit a form. I would like to add the POST variable though (param). Basically, i want the page to be redirected to test.aspx with param=paramvalue and I can't use GET for security reasons.

Comment: Then ajax isn't the way to go. ajax is for doing things in the background without leaving the page you're on. You can, however, use javascript to fill in a form on the current page (or build it dynamically) and trigger that form's submit method, which sends you to the new page.

Comment: Is there a way with jquery to add POST params to the form? or should I use the old JS way?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to add it with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to submit a form, you need to do `$('#formid').submit();`. What you have above is for an AJAX request. You need to pass a success callback function to the post function if you want to do something with the returned data.

**Example**:
See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Drackir/KKDDK/)

**HTML**

```
<button id="testbtn">button</button>
<div id="testdiv"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $('#testbtn').click(function() {
        $.post('/echo/html/', //This just echo's the html parameter's value back
               { html: "Just testing!" },
               function(text) {
                   $("#testdiv").html(text);
               });
    });
});
```

**Edit**
Based on your comments. You can add a hidden input element with the value you want to the form using jquery. Try something like this:

```
var yourdatavar = "data you want to post";
$('<input type="hidden">').val(yourdatavar).appendTo('#formid');
$('#formid').submit();
```

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Drackir/kvMDn/1/) for a working example.

Comment: Just in case someone reads this answer: Be very careful adding new DOM elements. Say client side validation fails and no POST is performed. That element is still going to be submitted in the next POST, even if it's no longer wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will submit an invisible form to test.apsx page with the desired parameter.

```
<form id="formToSubmit" action="test.apsx" method="post" style="display:none;">
  <input type="hidden" name="param" value="paramValue"/>
</form>

<a href="#" onclick="$('#formToSubmit').submit();">Submit the page</a>
```